# Calcular idade a partir da data de nascimento

Tags: c#, winforms

Criar um programa onde o usuário possa inserir seu nome e a data de nascimento. Em seguida deverá clicar em um botão que deverá exibir uma mensagem contendo sua idade.

Comment: O que você fez? Qual a dúvida?

Comment: fiz a parte gráfica apenas, botei uma TextBox, duas Label "nome" e "data de nascimento", um Button "Calcular Idade", e uma DateTimerPicker. Somente isso. Minha duvidas são os comandos para calcular a idade exibir na tela

Comment: Tem que digitar a data (no seu caso escolher) e na hora do calculo informar a quantidade de anos, pela data atual?

Comment: Sim, Isso mesmo!

Comment: mude o titulo da sua pergunta, perguntado sobre calculo de anos de uma data em C#

Comment: coloquei a resposta meio redirecionado com os comentários.

Comment: e pra aparecer em formato de mensagem na tela eu boto "MessageBox.Show("{0}");" é isso?

Comment: eu fiz a edição.

Answer (score 7):

Temos que considerar que a idade é determinada a partir da diferença em anos, e se o dia do nascimento for maior que o dia atual, então subtrair uma unidade:

**Exemplo: Nascimento em 10/01/1980**

- se hoje é 10/01/2000 => 2000 - 1980 = 20 anos
- se hoje é 09/01/2000 => 2000 - 1980 = 20, mas temos que subtrair 1 pois o dia é anterior ao do nascimento => 20 - 1 = 19 anos

A melhor forma de fazer isso que eu achei (https://stackoverflow.com/a/1404/195417):

```
var birthdate = new DateTime(1980, 1, 10);
var today = new DateTime(2000, 1, 9);
var age = today.Year - birthdate.Year;
if (birthdate > today.AddYears(-age)) age--;
```